# how to use another module's main fuction

Tags: python, program-entry-point, argparse, argv

I have a piece of python script where I need to call a `main(argv)` function from another script. The other one (name it `second.py`) with the `main()`also has some other functions which will be called later during the invokation of `main(argv)`, e.g., `check1`, `check2` etc. There is the entry point of the script defined there as well: 
 
`if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))`

So my question is when I made a call to the `main` from the other script I get some errors, I want to call this function in the first script, how can I achieve this goal?

For more information, this is how `main(argv)` looks like in `first.py`:

```
def main(argv):
    args = _parse_args(argv)
    settings = {
        "branch" : args.branch
    }
    if settings["branch"] == "master"
        check1()
    else:
        check2()
```

And the `_parse_args(args)` is the command-line interface:

```
def _parse_args(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="something",
                                     formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument("-b",
                        "--branch",
                        dest="branch",
                        type=check_non_empty_string,
                        help="The current branch",
                        required=True
                       )

    parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                    const=sum, default=max,
                    help='sum the integers
                        nargs="*")

    return parser.parse_args(args)
```

The way I call the `main()` function in the first module is like: 
`call = second.main(sys.argv[1:])`. Any help would be appreciated.

The traceback message logs:

```
  File "/src/first.py", line 91, in deliver_table
    call = second.main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/src/second.py", line 427, in main
    args = _parse_args(argv)
  File "/src/second.py", line 51, in _parse_args
    return parser.parse_args(args)
  File "/app/python/2.7.5/LMWP3/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1688, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/app/python/2.7.5/LMWP3/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1720, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/app/python/2.7.5/LMWP3/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1944, in _parse_known_args
    self.error(_('argument %s is required') % name)
  File "/app/python/2.7.5/LMWP3/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2361, in error
    self.exit(2, _('%s: error: %s\n') % (self.prog, message))
  File "/app/python/2.7.5/LMWP3/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2349, in exit
  _ sys.exit(status)
SystemExit: 2
```

Comment: Please list your errors.

Comment: Try "import second" in the first python script?

Comment: Echoing @NonStatic, have you actually imported the other module?

Comment: @NonStatic yeah I imported second, it was not the problem

Comment: @e.maguire yes i did

Comment: Then, show people the error will be very helpful.

Comment: @e.maguire the error is just a bunch of traceback messages, says where it goes wrong. In this case, it says `call = secondModule.main(sys.argv[1:])` is causing the problem but without giving any actual reason

Comment: @maoyi traceback is all we're asking for here, that's how Python tattles on bad code. Please provide the full traceback so we can diagnose this issue.

Comment: What problem?  Besides a traceback, the error always has a message and type.  That's what we need to see, even if it doesn't make sense to you!

Comment: the traceback is updated now. Thank you for checking!

Comment: I highly doubt that there was no error thrown and a full traceback was given. Are you sure this is the entire output?

Comment: Looks like the `parser` is throwing a missing argument error.  Didn't it also show a `usage` message?  In any case '-b' is the only required argument.  How are you calling this script? What's the commandline?  Are you using `pycharm` or `spyder` or some other fancy ide?  It might also help if you printed `sys.argv`.

Comment: Have you tested the `second.main()` in the `second.py` file? I think the problem is the way you using `parser.parse_args(args)`.